# "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" problem with passing data to a back-end (local) server

Tags: javascript, express, xmlhttprequest, cors

I am having a problem with an XMLHttpRequest. I have a simple front-end loading a file and passing it to the back-end to create smart contracts. If I make a single request it works fine, but when I try and load a file with over 200 lines, I do not use the submit button in the form but rather a function I created and I get a CORS error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/deploy_client' from
>   origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

I am using JavaScript and Node.JS with the Express library. I am running the backend on port 80 and the frontend on 8080.

The code for the front-end is:

```
<form id="myForm" action="http://localhost:80/deploy_client" method="POST">
  Platform address: <input type="text" name="platformAddress"><br>
  Insurer Address: <input type="text" name="insurerAddress"><br>
  Client UIC: <input type="text" id="clientUIC" name="clientUIC"><br>
  Client Name: <input type="text" id="clientName" name="clientName"><br>
  Client Group: <input type="text" id="clientGroup" name="clientGroup"><br>
  NACE: <input type="text" id="clientNACE" name="clientNACE"><br>
  Credit Line: <input type="text" id="clientCreditLine" name="clientCreditLine"><br>
  Credit Line Date: <input type="text" id="clientCreditLineDate" name="clientCreditLineDate"><br>
  Currency: <input type="text" id="clientCurrency" name="clientCurrency"><br>
  City: <input type="text" id="clientCity" name="clientCity"><br>
  Country: <input type="text" id="clientCountry" name="clientCountry"><br>

  Import Client Data: <input id="filePath" onchange='importClientData(event)' name="filePath" type="file" accept=".csv"><br>
  <button id="createClient" onclick='deployClient()'>Deploy Client</button>
</form>

<script>

    function deployClient()
        {

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:80/deploy_client", true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        xhr.send();
        }

    function importClientData(event) {
        var input = event.target;
        console.log("File Path: "         + input);

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function(){
            var newLine=String.fromCharCode(13)+String.fromCharCode(10);
            var clientLines=reader.result.split(newLine);
            var numLines = clientLines.length;

            console.log("clientLines[0]: " + clientLines[0]);

            var myColumn;
            for (var i=1;i<numLines;i++)
                {
                myColumn = clientLines[i].split(",");

                var myClientUIC = myColumn[0];
                var myClientName = myColumn[1];
                var myClientGroup = myColumn[2];
                var myClientCity = myColumn[5];
                var myClientCountry = myColumn[7];
                var myCreditLine = parseInt(myColumn[8])*1000000;                
                // 25569 = 1/1/1970 start of Unix time
                var myCreditLineDate = (parseInt(myColumn[9])-25569)*86400;
                var myCurrency = myColumn[10];
                var myNACE = myColumn[11];

                console.log("myClientUIC: "         + myClientUIC);
                console.log("myClientName: "        + myClientName);
                console.log("myClientGroup: "        + myClientCity);
                console.log("myClientCity: "        + myClientCity);
                console.log("myClientCountry: "     + myClientCountry);
                console.log("myCreditLine: "        + myCreditLine);
                console.log("myCreditLineDate: "    + myCreditLineDate);
                console.log("myCurrency: "          + myCurrency);
                console.log("myNACE: "              + myNACE);

                if (myClientUIC != "") // This avoids trying to load empty rows
                    {
                    // Call portfolio smart contract to create client
                    document.getElementById("clientUIC").innerHTML = myClientUIC;
                    document.getElementById("clientName").innerHTML = myClientName;
                    document.getElementById("clientGroup").innerHTML = myClientGroup;
                    document.getElementById("clientNACE").innerHTML = myNACE;
                    document.getElementById("clientCreditLine").innerHTML = myCreditLine;
                    document.getElementById("clientCreditLineDate").innerHTML = myCreditLineDate;
                    document.getElementById("clientCurrency").innerHTML = myCurrency;
                    document.getElementById("clientCity").innerHTML = myClientCity;
                    document.getElementById("clientCountry").innerHTML = myClientCountry;

                    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:80/deploy_client", true);
                    xhr.withCredentials = true;
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                    xhr.send({ 'request': "authentication token" });
                    //xhr.send();
                    } // if (myClientID <> "")
                }
            };
        reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
        }; // function openInvoiceFile(event) {

</script>
```

The code for the back-end is:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

const Web3 = require("web3");
const HDWalletProvider = require("@truffle/hdwallet-provider");

require('dotenv').config();
const provider = new HDWalletProvider(process.env.MNEMONIC, process.env.INFURA_URL);

var contract    = require("@truffle/contract");

const platformArtifacts = require('./build/contracts/Platform.json');
var platformContract = contract(platformArtifacts);
platformContract.setProvider(provider);

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 

function convertStringX(myString, len)
    {
    var myBuffer = [];
    var temp = Buffer.from(myString);

    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) { 
        // eliminate empty characters (different than spaces which are 0x20)
        if (i < myString.length)
            myBuffer.push(temp[i]);
        else
            myBuffer.push(0x0);         
        } 

    console.log(myBuffer);
    return myBuffer;
    }

var myPlatform;
const platformAddress = "0x...";

async function instantiatePlatform(deployedAddress) {
    myPlatform = await platformContract.at(deployedAddress);
    console.log("myPlatform address " + myPlatform.address);
    }

instantiatePlatform(platformAddress);

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    // Handle the get for this route
  });

app.all('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
    next();
});

app.post('/deploy_client', (req, res, next) => {

    var insurerAddress = '0x...';
    var myClientUIC = req.body.clientUIC;
    myClientUIC = convertStringX(myClientUIC, 16);
    console.log("myClientUIC "+ myClientUIC);
    var myClientName = req.body.clientName;
    myClientName = convertStringX(myClientName, 16);
    console.log("myClientName "+ myClientName);
    var myClientGroup = req.body.clientGroup;
    myClientGroup = convertStringX(myClientGroup, 16);
    console.log("myClientGroup "+ myClientGroup);
    var myClientNACE = req.body.clientNACE;
    console.log("myClientNACE "+ myClientNACE); 
    var myCreditLine = parseInt(req.body.clientCreditLine);
    console.log("myCreditLine "+ myCreditLine);
    var myCreditLineDate = parseInt(req.body.clientCreditLineDate);
    console.log("myCreditLineDate "+ myCreditLineDate);
    var myClientCurrency = req.body.clientCurrency;
    myClientCurrency = convertStringX(myClientCurrency, 3);
    console.log("myClientCurrency "+ myClientCurrency);
    var myClientCity = req.body.clientCity;
    myClientCity = convertStringX(myClientCity, 32);
    console.log("myClientCity "+ myClientCity);
    var myClientCountry = req.body.clientCountry;
    myClientCountry = convertStringX(myClientCity, 3);
    console.log("myClientCountry "+ myClientCountry);
    console.log("insurerAddress "+ insurerAddress);

    myPlatform.createClient(myClientUIC, myClientName, myClientGroup, 
        myClientNACE, insurerAddress, myCreditLine, myCreditLineDate, myClientCurrency, myClientCity, myClientCountry,
        { from:provider.getAddress() })
        .once('transactionHash', function(hash) {
            console.log("TxHash: " + hash);
        }).on('receipt', function(receipt) { console.log("receipt: " + JSON.stringify(receipt)); })
            .then(function(result) {
            console.log ("success - client address: " + result.address)
        }, function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });

    });

const port = 80;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});
```

I am really new to the whole CORS story and fairly green behind the ears with server calls. I would appreciate any help you can give me. I have tried to find something online, but although I have found lots of different pages, I cannot seem to find the right answer. Thanks!

The solution is to add the CORS package and include:

```
const cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors())
```

and for the whitelist the code is:

```
var whitelist = ['localhost:8080']
var corsOptionsDelegate = function (req, callback) {
    var corsOptions;
    if (whitelist.indexOf(req.header('Origin')) !== -1) {
        corsOptions = { origin: true } // reflect (enable) the requested origin in the CORS response
    } else {
        corsOptions = { origin: false } // disable CORS for this request
    }
    callback(null, corsOptions) // callback expects two parameters: error and options
}
```

The above solution solves the CORS problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) package in you server file? 
When you are making a request to a server from any client, the server needs to check from its white list and send the appropriate value to **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** Header. Your server is not responding with this header at all.

Comment: Thanks! I loaded it, but I now get a slightly different error: "xInvestFileLoader.html:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/deploy_client' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute." Any idea why I still get an error?

Comment: When there is `*` in the header, then the response data is not accessible in the browser even though the Preflight request was successful. You need to whitelist `localhost:8080` on the server. At the bottom of the documentation it explains how to do it using the `var whitelist = [ ]`

Comment: Thanks. Adding the code regarding the Whitelist solved my problem. I added the necessary changes I made above. Thanks again for your help.